# ActionScript SmartFoxServer user.getUserId() is always 0

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey so am facing this problem for 2 days now i tried reading the documentation didn't solve it,

So then i tried doing it myself couldn't fix it!

The code:

```
function handleInternalEvent(evt) { 
  var Event = evt.name
  trace("Event:" + Event)

  if (evt.name == "loginRequest")
  {
    var error = ""

    var nick = evt["nick"].split("~")[0]
    var pass = evt["pass"]
    var chan = evt["chan"]

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + nick + "'"
    var SQL_Result = dbase.executeQuery(sql)

    if (SQL_Result != null && SQL_Result.size() > 0) {

            var tempRow = SQL_Result.get(0)

            var user_id = tempRow.getItem("id")
            }

            var obj = _server.loginUser(nick, pass, chan)

            if (obj.success == true) {
                var user = _server.getUserByChannel(chan)
                user.properties.put("id", user_id)
                trace("UserID:" + user.getUserId())
                }
    }
}
```

Please note that the user id in the database is 1 and not 0

I don't see any problem with this any help is grateful thanks

Also when i trace user_id which is the Database id i need

It shows
[wqw.as]: UserID : 1

Output of trace:

```
    DB Manager Activated ( com.mysql.jdbc.Driver )
    Zone: zone_master

    somerandomroomw... (id: 1, max: 40, pass:N)
09:31:04.838 - [ INFO ] > Zone Extension [ zm ] created, for zone:zone_master
[wqw.as]: Test - SmartFoxServer

--- [ Server Starting ] ---------------------------------

Server address: All

Server port   : 5588

09:31:04.881 - [ INFO ] > [TaskScheduler] ... started ::

09:31:04.882 - [ INFO ] > [BlueBoxHandler]... started ::

09:31:04.883 - [ INFO ] > [EventWriter] ..... started :: 1 thread(s)

09:31:04.884 - [ INFO ] > [SystemHandler] ... started :: 1 thread(s)

09:31:04.885 - [ INFO ] > [ExtensionHandler]. started :: 1 thread(s)

09:31:04.886 - [ INFO ] > [DeadChannelsPolicy: strict]

09:31:04.886 - [ INFO ] > Server is up and running!

[wqw.as]: Event:serverReady

[wqw.as]: Event:loginRequest

[wqw.as]: UserID:0
```

Comment: Try `trace("UserID : " + user_id); `. Could you show us what's `user` ?

Comment: It shows the corrent userid that is in the db which is UserID : 1 But when i use user.getUserId() it shows 0

Comment: I don't know what's your `user` object, but you should verify if `user.properties.put("id", user_id)` do it's job if you have access of course. And you can show properties of `user` object using, for example, a for loop like this : `for(var prop in user){ trace('prop = '+user[prop]); } `. Also, you can try just : `trace(user.id)`.

Comment: This might help you understand more so for some reason its not getting the right ID which is = 1 ,It's getting the id of 0 i can't seem to understand why also  the code of the actionscript might make you understand!, var usr = _server.getUserByChannel(chan)
  trace("User ID: " + usr.getUserId())  <<<This trace will trace the user id of 0 but i need it = to 1 since thats my database user id thank you for your help!

Comment: I understood the situation, but did you tried what I told you in my last comment ?

Comment: Yes and i got a huge long trace, Should i show it   link:http://pastebin.com/4Ae59THc

Comment: I see your output and the smartfoxserver online doc. I think that you can't change the user id, it's a read only information, however you can attach your own custom properties to the `User()` object by using `user.properties.put('prop', value);`.